# Proof of algebraic limit theorem for products of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $\lim a_n = a$ and $\lim b_n = b$. Prove $\lim a_n b_n = ab$

I've encountered this proof in Abbot's Understanding Analysis, but I came up with an alternative closure of the proof so I want to check if it makes sense.

I will skip the initial portion of the proof.

...

$$|a_n b_n - ab|= \dots \leq \dots = |b_n||a_n - a|+|a||b_n-b| \leq M |a_n - a|+|a||b_n-b| \quad \text{(*)}$$

Last inequality holds because $b_n$ is bounded so there exists $M > 0$ such that $M > |b_n| \space \forall n \in \mathbb N$. The proof continues by setting $\epsilon_{a_n}, \epsilon_{b_n}$ as follows $|a_n - a|<\epsilon_{a_n}=\frac{\epsilon}{M\cdot2}$ and $|b_n -b|<\epsilon_{b_n}=\frac{\epsilon}{|a|\cdot2}$. When $a \neq 0$ the proof is straight forward, everything cancels out. The case when $a=0$ is left as an exercise.

My question here: could the continuation be $\text{*} \leq M |a_n - a|+ M_2|b_n-b|$, where $M_2 > 0$ such that $M_2 \geq |a|$? Then if $a \neq 0$ we set $\epsilon_{b_n} = \frac{\epsilon}{M_2 \cdot 2}$ and if $a=0$ we set $\epsilon_{a_n} = \frac {\epsilon}{M}$ and $\epsilon_{b_n}=\epsilon$, finally getting
$$M |a_n - a|+ M_2|b_n-b| < \begin{cases} M \frac {\epsilon}{M\cdot 2} + M_2 \frac{\epsilon}{M_2 \cdot 2} = \epsilon & \quad a \neq 0 \\
M \frac {\epsilon}{M} + 0 \cdot \epsilon = \epsilon & \quad a = 0 \end{cases} $$ Also I omitted stating that we choose $N_{a_n}, N_{b_n}$ based on the respective $\epsilon_{a_n}, \epsilon_{b_n}$ choices etc., and at the end we pick $N = \max (N_{a_n}, N_{b_n})$.

**Addendum:**
As @FShrike said in the comments we can avoid the cases by picking $M_2>|a|$ while letting $\epsilon_{b_n} = \frac{\epsilon}{M_2 \cdot 2}$, hence arriving at
$$M |a_n - a|+ M_2|b_n-b| < M \frac {\epsilon}{M\cdot 2} + M_2 \frac{\epsilon}{M_2 \cdot 2} = \epsilon$$

Avoiding the cases was the initial motivation for this direction, but I hallucinated errors arising from letting $M_2 > |a|$ and got tangled up in cases

Comment: that works. You could also avoid cases by taking $M_2>|a|$ strictly, or indeed $M_2>\max(M,|a|)$

Comment: @FShrike Tbh avoiding the cases was the whole motivation for this, but while writing this up I got scared that I couldn't take $M_2>|a|$, for some reason.. now I see that I can. Many thanks! Feel free to promote to answer and I'll mark it as answer